# update column of mysql database table after record is updated

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have a strange problem. I have mysql database table. The few tables are updated from php script (I can't access the script), Now I need to update another column (count column whicih will increment by one each time the row is updated) using update trigger. Can some one help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You already say, you should do this in an update trigger. So, write one?

Comment: If you can't access the script how you think you will update it?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Yes I know this can b done in trigger but I can't write query.

Comment: @Ingus I know the script is updating my table and in trigger on update I want to update my required column.

Comment: I suggest you start writing the trigger. Google a little, try a little. See where you get stuck. Then come back here with what you have.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you were right and I found solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I was looking for.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_name`;
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`server` 
TRIGGER `trigger_name` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name`
FOR EACH ROW 
Set new.penalty = new.penalty+1
```

This worked for me.